# How to Resolve - "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" Error in C#

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

public partial class FormCreationWithDataStoraget : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void sbmt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data Source=RAJIM  -PC;Initial Catalog=RajiDatabase;Integrated Security=True"].ConnectionString;
        string insertSql = "INSERT INTO FamilyDetails(FirstName,LastName,Gender,Age,Relationship,MobileNumber)" + "values(@FirstName,@LaseName,@Gender,,@Age,@,@MobileNumber)";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand();
        scmd.Connection = conn;
        scmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        scmd.CommandText = insertSql;

        SqlParameter firstname = new SqlParameter("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40);
        firstname.Value = tbx.Text.ToString();
        scmd.Parameters.Add(firstname);

        SqlParameter lastname = new SqlParameter("@LaseName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40);
        lastname.Value = tbx1.Text.ToString();
        scmd.Parameters.Add(lastname);

        SqlParameter gender=new SqlParameter("@Gender",SqlDbType.VarChar,40);
        gender.Value = rbt.SelectedItem.ToString();
        scmd.Parameters.Add(gender);

        SqlParameter age = new SqlParameter("@Age", SqlDbType.Int);
        age.Value = tbx2.Text.ToString();
        scmd.Parameters.Add(age);

        SqlParameter relationship = new SqlParameter("@Relationship", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40);
        relationship.Value = tbx3.Text.ToString();
        scmd.Parameters.Add(relationship);

        SqlParameter mobilenumber=new SqlParameter("@MobileNumber",SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);
        mobilenumber.Value = tbx4.Text.ToString();
        scmd.Parameters.Add(mobilenumber);


        try
        {
            conn.Open();
           scmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           Response.Write("User Registration successful");
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            string errorMessage = "Error in registering user";
            errorMessage += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(errorMessage);

        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you debug your code? Do you know what line exactly is breaking it? Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data Source=RAJIM  -PC;Initial Catalog=RajiDatabase;Integrated Security=True"].ConnectionString; ......This is the Error line

Comment: post your web.config where your connection strings are being defined.

Comment: I didn't Add any code on Web.Config File

Comment: This is my We.config file:  <connectionStrings>
<add 
    name="MyConnectionString"
    connectionString="Data Source=RAJIM-PC;Initial Catalog=RajiDatabase;Integrated Security=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>

Comment: Next time you ask a question please provide a little more information rather than just pasting in a chunk of code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this line is causing your problem:

```
string insertSql = "INSERT INTO FamilyDetails(FirstName,LastName,Gender,Age,Relationship,MobileNumber)" + "values(@FirstName,@LaseName,@Gender,,@Age,@,@MobileNumber)";
```

Specifically:

```
@FirstName,@LaseName,@Gender,,@Age,@,@MobileNumber
```

It Should Be:

```
@FirstName,@LaseName,@Gender,@Age,@Relationship,@MobileNumber
```

Comment: Still I'm getting the same Error..the error line is (string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data Source=RAJIM  -PC;Initial Catalog=RajiDatabase;Integrated Security=True"].ConnectionString;)

Comment: Runtime Error (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that this line:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data Source=RAJIM  -PC;Initial Catalog=RajiDatabase;Integrated Security=True"].ConnectionString;
```

is not retrieving any object because you don't have a `ConnectionString` defined your `web.config` with the name of "Data Source=RAJIM ..." so basically calling the `.ConnectionString` at the end of it breaks it.

Add the "Data Source=RAJIM..." line as a connection string in  your `web.config` (more info on connection strings [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)).

Once you give your connection string a name, i.e., "MyConnectionString" then change your code to be:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Added the data source in Web.config file but now its showing runtime error on "throw new Exception(errorMessage);" line..Error name is (Error in registering userIncorrect syntax near ','.)

Comment: @rajendranm, you have an extra comma in this line `@Gender,,@Age`